# Understanding Trig equations

Tags: trigonometry

I understand why $\sin(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ has two answers, $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ but I don't understand why $\tan(x)=1$ only has one solution (according to my book and other places I've looked online) $\frac{\pi}{4}$.  Why isn't $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ also a solution given that tan is positive in Q1 and Q3 and at $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ both $\sin$ and $\cos$ are $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Note that the interval is not given.

Comment: $\sin(x) = \sqrt{3}/{2}$ has infinitely many solutions, as does $\tan(x) = 0$.  That being said, I don't think that $\pi/3$ solves $\tan(x) = 0$.  Nor do I agree with your assertion that $\sin(4\pi/3) = \cos(4\pi/3) = -\sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: Sorry meant $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ editing

Comment: Do you mean $\tan(x) = 1$? Regardless, both equations have infinitely many solutions as @XanderHenderson mentioned.

Comment: You ask "why isn't $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ also a solution," yet $x=\frac{5\pi}{4}$ is indeed a solution: $\tan(\frac{5\pi}{4})=1$

Comment: Yes, edited to fix.  So in this case since there is no interval given it's assumed that it's just $\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi*n$ ?

Comment: @dstarh No, it's $\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi\cdot n$. I think you have a typo in your question, since $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the interval is not given, you would be wise to assume it's from minus infinity to positive infinity.

Consequently you should give the general solution.

So,
$$\sin(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
has solutions,
$$\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k$$
or
$$\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi k$$
for integer values of $k$

Shall I leave you to do similar for the other equations in your question ?

Top Tip : Drawing a graph of the appropriate trigonometric function is helpful.

Comment: Ok since there are 2 general solutions to sin(x) then you list both but since it's only one technical solution for tan(x) you would only list the one?  That makes more sense.  Thanks

Comment: If the interval IS given for ex  from $0 < x < 2\pi$ then would both solutions be valid for the tan equation?

Comment: The period of the $tan(x)$ graph is just $\pi$ radians so you can typically compact it's general solutions more than for general solutions from the $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ graphs with their period of $2\pi$

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  For whatever reason my professor skipped graphing of tan and just focused on sin/cos

Comment: Just to be clear : $tan(x)=1$ has the two solutions $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ in the interval $0<x<2\pi$

Comment: Thanks we only did practice problems where an interval was given which is why I was confused.

Comment: You are welcome; I'm pleased to have been able to help.